# If I know the API Name, how can I get and work with the Schema.ChildRelationship?

Tags: apex, api, schema, childrelationship, generics

Like many SFDC developers, we have SObjects which are related to other custom relationships.

So, for example, `MyCustomObject__c` could have a relationship with `MyCustomRelationship__c` which in Apex we might normally access with `MyCustomObject__c.MyCustomRelationship__r`

Of course, this isn't a one-off scenario, so we might also have `MyCustomObject2__c.MyCustomRelationship2__r`, `MyCustomObject3__c.MyCustomRelationship3__r`, etc.
And of course these relationships don't need to be one-to-one or so neatly organized.

But the thing is, we want a generic way to process some of these, so we'd like to make a method with a signature like:

`doSomething(SObject sObj, SObjectField sObjectField)`

only these aren't actually SObjectFields but rather Schema.ChildRelationships, so in actually we would need a signature like:

`doSomething(SObject sObj, Schema.ChildRelationship childRelationship)`

But then this still present two problems:

1. How can I actually get the value for Schema.ChildRelationship from the API name (e.g. `MyCustomObject__c.MyCustomRelationship__r`)?
2. Having Schema.ChildRelationship, how I can apply it to my SObject to do something like

   `List<SObject> relatedSObjectList = sObj.get(childRelationship)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first.

To get the child records if you know the relationship name, you pass a `String` argument to the `SObject.getSObjects` method:

```
MyObject__c parent = new MyObject__c();
String relatioonshipName = 'Children__r';
List<Child__c> children = parent.getSObjects(relationshipName);
```

Now back to your first question. There is no way to get a specific `ChildRelationship` without looping, but it also doesn't help you if you already have the relationship name as a string. Basically, your loop structure would look like:

```
ChildRelationship relationship;
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.MyObject__c.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relation.getRelationshipName() = relationshipName)
    {
        relationship = relation;
    }
}
```

If you decide you need to do this looping (for example checking permissions, I highly suggest you implement a [`DescribeCache`](https://github.com/apexlarson/FluentQuery/blob/master/src/classes/DescribeCache.cls) where you cache these relationships and call a signature like:

```
public static ChildRelationship getChildRelationship(SObjectType sObjectType, String name)
```